# How to use sql user defined types in entity framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sqlclr

How can I use a User Defined Type - written by SQL CLR - in Entity Framework?
This type is designed to implement Persian Date Data Types in the right way.
I tried to use HasColumnType() to use this custom type:

```
modelBuilder.Properties()
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
            .Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("PersianDate"));
```

but it wasn't successful and I got this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, String name)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)
>      at 
>   ...

I'm sure that this error is result of using HasColumnType(). Also I'm sure that this types works correctly in my database.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, I'm also agree that you have declared wrong value inside `HasColumnType("PersianDate")`.

Based from MSDN, `HasColumnType` configures the data type of database column, usually with primitive data types (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.stringcolumnconfiguration.hascolumntype(v=vs.113).aspx) for more information).

Probably current implementation of EF 6 has some limitations regarding user-defined data types, since user-defined types require checking routine that the type is not already created when initializing DB.

As a workaround for user-defined type, declare Persian date as a column using `datetime2` on SQL side (`datetime` has minimum limit of January 1, 1753, thus won't work for Persian years) and map it as `DateTime`:

```
modelBuilder.Properties()
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
            .Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Additional reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8143626/6378815

Comment: probably you're right, it's just working with primitive types. Note that I added this custom type in my database before scaffolding any DateTime related migration. Also datetime2 has some limitations and I don't want to use that, one of them is that it's possible to insert wrong date in database.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto thank you so much you saved my time