# Can the code-first features of EF 4.1 and greater be used when the DB schema is unknown until runtime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

This does not seem to be explicitly listed as a feature in any of the sparse examples I can find, for example:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/336187/code-first-practical-case

or

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-code-first-walkthrough.aspx

But I think the DbContext docs at least imply that it's possible:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.103).aspx

> DbContext is usually used with a derived type that contains
>   DbSet properties for the root entities of the model. These
>   sets are automatically initialized when the instance of the derived
>   class is created.

My goal is to use the EF to access a DB through a WCF data service from a Silverlight client, where the some of the columns are unknown at runtime.  Any better ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Could you explain more about what you are trying to achieve?  For example, could a more general model be what you are after?

Comment: @dtryon For example, I would like to populate a DataGrid or define a form based on a standard set of tables, any of which might contain a handful of custom columns for a given user.  Right now, I am using a WCF data service build on top of an EF model, but this means that the tables are static members of my assembly.

Comment: If you do have such a dynamic UI, could you not model the data in a more dynamic way?  You could use a meta-model technique and have an entity for column, set etc.  Just an idea, maybe it doesn't fit with what you are attempting.

Comment: @dtryon, do you have some specific examples of which technologies you're referring to here?  Meta-modeling sounds like an academic topic...  and alas, I am stuck with the DB I have.  The new requirement is that we support custom tables when they are needed.

Comment: I think what @dtryon refers to is an [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). This model is heavily criticized, but there are cases where there is no better alternative. Anyway, since your stuck to the DB as is, this model is not an option.

Comment: @GertArnold I wasn't referring to EAV directly, however, just trying to make a data model to the problem.  As you say, though, it wouldn't do here anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither WCF or EF is suitable technology for this situation. WCF and its autogenerated proxies expects compile time defined model - you can avoid this but as a result you will not work with strongly typed data contracts but with "generic data" and you will work with them on XML or JSON level.

In case of EF it is even worse there is no easy workaround to get dynamic behavior. You can change DB or even mapping (but not with code first - only with EDMX) in dynamic way but still at the end you need compiled classes representing your mapped data.

The part of documentation you are referencing is not about dynamic creation of mapping but only about dynamic initialization of mapping defined in design time.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have any recommendations for technologies that might work for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, here is a synopsis of how to change the EDMX files to match a DB discovered at runtime:

1. Get and parse schema from the database (simple XML)
2. Put the schema in a format that is comparable with the EDMX metadata (more complex XML)
3. Use a tool like this one:  http://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com/  to make the changes to the metadata (some assembly required)
4. Instantiate the data model

There is a commercial tool to do the same, but it's not free:  http://huagati.com/dbmltools/

And here is the best list of other, more palatable options:  [Modifying an Entity Framework Model at Run-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019895/modifying-an-entity-framework-model-at-run-time/4048574#4048574)